# Symfony Validate TimeType

Tags: symfony, validation, symfony4

So I am using TimeType fields in my FormType and was wondering how the validation might work there.

To be more precise, I have two TimeTypes and I want to check that the second one is after the first one.

I've used the Validation constraint GreaterThan, which correctly validates my field. However I have 2 problems which come in my mind:

- should I also use LessThan on the first field?
- the validation message outputs that my field has to be greather than "01.01.1970 05:00" which is not the error message I expect (date should be removed) how do I achieve this? Also translations should work for that.

Thanks

No solution yet - anyone knows a fix?

Comment: Sure, just write your [own constraint & validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html). You could apply custom rules, custom error messages…